# Divs don't stop following scroll at footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried a lot of solutions but I cant make the divs stop following the scroll at the footer.
Here is my code to make the divs follow the scroll (`colderecha` and `colizquierda` are my divs that follow the scroll):

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var top = $('#colizquierda').offset().top - parseFloat($('#colizquierda').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        //if y > top, it means that if we scroll down any more, parts of our element will be outside the viewport
        //so we move the element down so that it remains in view.
        if (y >= top) {
            var difference = y - top;
            $('#colizquierda').css("top",difference);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () { 
    var top = $('#colderecha').offset().top - parseFloat($('#colderecha').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        //if y > top, it means that if we scroll down any more, parts of our element will be outside the viewport
        //so we move the element down so that it remains in view.
        if (y >= top) {
            var difference = y - top;
            $('#colderecha').css("top",difference);
        }
    });
});
```

What I have tried:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    checkOffset();
});
function checkOffset() {
    if ($('#colizquierda').offset().top + $('#colizquierda').height() >= $('#footer').offset().top - 10)
        $('#colizquierda').css('position', 'absolute');
    if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#footer').offset().top)
        $('#colizquierda').css('position', 'fixed');
    if ($('#colderecha').offset().top + $('#colderecha').height() >= $('#footer').offset().top - 10)
        $('#colderecha').css('position', 'absolute');
    if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#footer').offset().top)
        $('#colderecha').css('position', 'fixed');
}
```

Comment: You will have to demonstrate **what** you have tried and what you have learned from that. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry im new at this website, I will  show what I have tried:

Comment: Being new is no excuse for not reading the available documentation and guidelines detailing how to ask questions in a beneficial way.